# Android textView onCreate changes

Tags: java, android, textview

I've creating a textView called textView1 using the Layout Editor on main.xml. I want to use a custom font so I a font set line of code into the onCreate but it doesn't seem to recongnize the name textView1

```
package com.mystraldesign.memorable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MemorableActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/optima.ttf"); 
        textView1.setTypeface(type);
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but this is my first time coding Android so still feeling my way around.

Comment: whether the below solution solved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextView textView1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_info);
Typeface type= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/optima.ttf");
textView1.setTypeface(type);
```

Comment: imran khan, I tried that but get an error text_info cannot be resolved or is not a field and it offers the fix of Migrating Code

Comment: ok you have textview with id text_info in your main.xml layout .if not then fisrt add a textview in main.xml layout for which u want to set custom font

Comment: Was being stupid. text_info should have been textView1. I'm so not used to Java

Comment: @JamesKraw : james just replace text_info by textview id to which you want to set typeface

Answer (score 2):

Please Intialize TextView in you code...

Try this:-

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      // Font path
      String fontPath = "fonts/optima.ttf";
      // text view label
      TextView textView1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
     // Loading Font Face
      Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
     // Applying font
      textView1.setTypeface(tf);
  }
```

Comment: This. The ADK does a lot for you, but it still can't magically create Java objects you haven't declared.